# Using Python to scrape without damage to the web

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote the following hybrid code.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome (executable_path="C:\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://example.com/welcome")

for i in range(6):
    source = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
    print(soup.prettify)
    time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()  
driver.close
```

This code allows me to get to the welcome page where I can manually enter username and password. I can read the HTML code and using bs4, trap a dynamic value. The value on the website is sent to my browser at about 2 Hz.  If I reduce the sleep time and make the passes in the loop large (>>> 6), am I limited to the refresh rate of the server?
In other words, is my loop (driver.page_source) requesting data from the server or is it only reading what the server sends at its desired rate? I do not want my code to tie up the server by asking for updated data by sending multiple (driver.page_source)s.

Comment: `page_source` just gets the source of the current page, it doesn't make a request to the server

Comment: @Matiiss I don't think so, it works even without internet signal, it seems like it just reads what already has been requested by the browser. The offcial doc is not very clear though https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source

Comment: @Matiiss Just because you see `GET_PAGE_SOURCE` it doesn't mean that it sends a request to server. Even `driver.current_url` has a similar syntax `GET_CURRENT_URL` but it surely doesn't send any request, it is just the url of the page. Moreover, notice that the `GET_X` commands are just constants, see https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.command

Comment: @soundwave I'm fairly certain it does send a GET request because that's pretty much what the constants have in the src, (type, url), however, they don't send it to the server (in this case whatever hosting example.com), but to some internal connection as indicated by the URLs ig, but that's irrelevant to this case anyways

Comment: If anyone is proficient in Wireshark, they could run a simple test... It has been a while since I used Wireshark.

Comment: I tested using a local flask server (werkzeug or sth), it doesn't send a request every time that attribute is accessed to the server (it does do really seem like it should send a request to somewhere, but certainly not to that server)

Comment: As I said before it's easy to verify if requests to server are sent or no: just run the first part of the code before the `for` loop, then disconnect your computer from the internet and finally run the rest of the code. The loop will run without problems, printing each time the page source

Comment: sound wave, I like your logic. Thank you all.